# Adding categorical features to each pixel of an image for use in CNN model

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-data, conv-neural-network, categorical-encoding

I am building a model which generates new image from an imput image. I have a training set of input images and desired generated images and I also have some categorical data for each pixel of an image which I want to use as aditional features for the model. Currently I am jusut converting categorical features to have a float value on the interval between 0 - 1 for each category in even spaced intervals:

- Feature 1: 1/n
- Feature 2: 2/n
- Feature 3: 3/n ....
- Feature n: n/n

Where **n** is the number of features. I then add this categorical feature matrix as a separate channel to the input image. I am wondering what are other aproaches for incorporating categorical data to CNN based models? How does one hot encoding work with CNNs? I have doubts because then I would essentiially create **n** sparse input channels and I have no experience with CNNs and sparse data.

Comment: Interesting problem. To clarify, do you mean that you have one feature with cardinality of n? So if each pixel is "good", "bad" or "ugly", then you'd encode them as either .33, .67, or 1 accordingly in a single channel. Do I understand correctly? You could also try one-hot encoding them, and then each level could have it's own channel of 0s and 1s. But idk if this will work well - it probably won't if cardinality is high.